# opencv error in drawcontours - eye motion detection python code

Tags: numpy, opencv

I am getting error while running the python code for eye motion detection,
I follow the steps in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kbdbZFT9NQI

```
#https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kbdbZFT9NQI
import cv2
import numpy
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("C:\\Users\\sinsbv\\Desktop\\Project\\Kaggle\\Tutorial_Mini_Project\\open_cv\\eye_recording.flv")
while True:
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    roi = frame[269:795,537:1416]
    gray_roi = cv2.cvtColor(roi,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray_roi = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_roi , (7  , 7) ,0)
    _,threshold = cv2.threshold(gray_roi,5,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    _, contours = cv2.findContours ( threshold , cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE )
    for cnt in contours:
        # ctr = numpy.array(cnt).reshape((-1,1,2)).astype(numpy.int32)
        cv2.drawContours(roi,cnt , -1,(0,0,255) ,3)

    cv2.imshow("threshold" , threshold)
    cv2.imshow("gray roi" , gray_roi)
    cv2.imshow("Roi" , roi)
    key = cv2.waitKey(30)
    if key == 27:
        break


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

expected result - detection of eye motion
actual result - below error,

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sinsbv/Desktop/Project/Kaggle/Tutorial_Mini_Project/open_cv/open_cv.py", line 14, in 
    cv2.drawContours(roi,cnt , -1,(0,0,255) ,3)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\drawing.cpp:2509: error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints > 0 in function 'cv::drawContours'

Comment: It's `contours, _ = cv2.findContours (threshold, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`, see the [doc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0).

Comment: ok,let me try that.

Comment: it worked!! thanks  HansHirse :)